# ECDH Shared key generation using BouncyCastle in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

I am trying to use the bouncycastle library to generate a sharedkey using ECDH ( p521 curve) in my c# application.

I have used the Microsoft's CngKey and the shared keys generated on the server and client is the same. However since this is not supported in Win XP , I am trying Bouncycastle.

The following is my code to generate my keypair and then get the server's X and Y and generate the server public key out of that.

```
X9ECParameters ecP = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-521");
ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N, ecP.H,   ecP.GetSeed());
IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator g = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDH");
g.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, new SecureRandom()));

// Client X and Y
BigInteger ax = ecP.G.X.ToBigInteger();
byte[] axb = ax.ToByteArray();
BigInteger ay = ecP.G.Y.ToBigInteger();
byte[] ayb = ay.ToByteArray();

// Generate Client Keypair
 AsymmetricCipherKeyPair aKeyPair = g.GenerateKeyPair();
 IBasicAgreement aKeyAgree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDH");
aKeyAgree.Init(aKeyPair.Private);


// Get Servers X and Y
Console.WriteLine("Enter X co-ordinate");
string BobXhex = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter Y co-ordinate");
string BobYhex = Console.ReadLine();

// Server public key
FpCurve c = (FpCurve)ecSpec.Curve;
ECFieldElement x = new FpFieldElement(c.Q, new BigInteger(BobXhex, 16));
ECFieldElement y = new FpFieldElement(c.Q, new BigInteger(BobYhex, 16));

ECPoint q = new FpPoint(ecP.Curve, x, y);
ECPublicKeyParameters publicKey = new ECPublicKeyParameters("ECDH", q,    SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP521r1);

// generate shared key
BigInteger k1 = aKeyAgree.CalculateAgreement(publicKey);
byte[] genKey = k1.ToByteArray();
```

I wanted to know if the above is the correct way of generating the shared key.
The shared key is not matching with the one generated on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: I found the issue. Hope this helps someone. The problem was in the X and Y values that I was sharing with my server. The X and Y needs to be obtained from the public key and not ecP.G.

Comment: I just want to warn you: BC's ECC code is pretty slow and probably vulnerable to timing attacks.